# how to query such that a group of rows are repeated exactly using mysql

Tags: mysql

Ive been trying to query where a group of row values repeat exactly . like this:

```
id       part_id    supplier    quantity
 1          1         A            20
 2          1         B            30

 3          2         A            11
 4          2         B            30

 5          3         A            20
 6          3         B            30
```

we can assume that each part_id will always have both A and B as the suppliers.

My problem is that I want to query for part_id where A=20 and B=30.

The result would be part_id : 1 and 3

How do I do that given that A and B are in 2 different rows? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sub-select would do:

```
SELECT id, part_id, supplier, quantity
FROM yourtable
WHERE part_id IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT part_id
   FROM yourtable
   WHERE ((supplier = 'A') and (quantity = 20)) 
      OR ((supplier = 'B') and (quantity = 30))
)
```

---

edit, ok. given the new info, try this for the subselect:

```
 SELECT part_id
 FROM yourtable
 WHERE ((supplier = 'A') and (quantity = 20)) 
      OR ((supplier = 'B') and (quantity = 30))
 GROUP BY part_id
 HAVING COUNT(part_id) = 2
```

find all the records where the a/b stuff maches, group by the part_id, but only return the part_ids where BOTH a/b parts match. so the case where a=11 will get ignored, because the count would only be 1 in that particular case.

Comment: Hi I tried this previously but having an OR in the subquery would also result in part_id = 2 being selected since it has a supplier - B where the quantity is 30. You cant use AND cause there is no way one row can have A-20 and B-30.

Comment: Ah. Gotcha. so select the rows in the pairs were only each "subrecord" a/b match the clauses.